# why UML is showing Android Adapter interface has a View and a ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, uml, intellij-14

Any anyone tell me why UML is showing Android Adapter interface has a View and a ViewGroup

i am using UML diagram auto generation with Intellij IDEA and i am looking at Android API 14[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the Android [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) Documentation you'll see that...

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the
>   underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data
>   items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item
>   in the data set.

And so...

> why UML is showing Android Adapter interface has a View and a
>   ViewGroup[?]

The obvious answer is because it does. A more direct answer is because the UML is showing the relationships. I imagine it's a matter of your UML settings. In reality you could show it all the way back to `Object`, however your UML diagrams should show only important information.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But what i am wondering is the Adapter interface do/can not have/hold any View/ViewGroup instance. The "has a" relationship in the UML diagram that an adapter "has a" View/ViewGroup is not found in the java code.

Comment: @BrianLai, sorry I guess I'm having trouble understanding. Are you saying the java source files for the `Adapter` interface do not mention these classes? That's true to the extent that it's an interface and these classes don't appear as variables in the source. However, there are instances of method parameters which are and the file includes `import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;` at the top. So it actually does.